# get exact UTC date & time if Android device time is wrong

Tags: android, datetime, utc

I changed my android phone time to Sep 28 , 2016 4:14 PM,now I'm using this below code to get Current UTC Time

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(f.format(new Date()));
```

**Output what I'm getting now:** 2016-09-28 10:43
**Expected Output :** 2016-09-27 10:43

How to get exact UTC date & time if my device time is wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You can giving time from public server time.
remember to add INTERNET permission in manifest.

```
String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";   
NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
long returnTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();
Date time = new Date(returnTime);
```

Comment: Instead of .getTransmitTimeStamp() I used getOrignateTimeStamp() and it started giving UTC corresponding to the time changed on my device. So don't use OriginateTime if you want Server UTC. Thanks for really useful code

Comment: where to get the NTPUDPClient and TimeInfo, in android there is no default NTPUDPClient and TimeInfo.

Answer (score 0):

If device time is wrong then you can retrieve date/time from the network(GSM/WIFI).It can be done by using below code

```
long networkTS = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getTime();
```

If networktime is old then you can call locationManager.requestSingleUpdate() and pass the network provider

Answer (score -2):

System.currentTimeMillis() does give you the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.